# Can Blender be used for high quality industrial design?

Tags: topology

I have been using Rhino for industrial designs but there are many cases that it is very difficult to carry it through because of lack of Rhino's freeform and flexibility. I want to switch to SubD softwares like blender. The problem in SubD softwares is distortion around edges in curved surfaces. For example, it is very hard to dig several custom shape holes on a sphere without distortion when you add subdivision and smooth it.
Please guide me. Is it worth to use Blender for industrial design (just for rendering not manufacturing)?
If yes then how can I learn SubD industrial modeling using Blender? My problen is getting a right topology in each situation.

Comment: If you really want to invest time (and maybe money) into this, it is possible. Have a look at the new course by CGmasters' Gleb Alexandrov and Aidy Burrows: [Hard Surface Modeling in Blender](https://cgmasters.net/training-courses/hard-surface-modeling-in-blender/).
Or have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EfUqNS9pOo) for how to do some basic things. Also look at the other videos of his channel, they're great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Blender is capable of doing high-quality industrial design, if you are willing to invest the time.

For getting appropriate topology, there is information available like http://www.topologyguides.com

Also, regarding your comment about distortion around holes cut into curved surfaces, Blender has the Shrinkwrap modifier that can you can use to smooth your surface after cutting.  For example, here's a sphere with an odd cutout.  On the left I used Shrinkwrap to mold it to a sphere, and on the right without Shrinkwrap. The reflections on the right sphere are distorted as you would expect with a SubD surface, but the reflections on the left are smooth around the edge of the cutout:

[image]

This is a *really* quick example so it's not perfect, but if you put effort into it you certainly can get great results.

See this link: https://www.blendernation.com/2016/04/14/shrinkwrap-modifier-hard-surface-modellers-best-friend/