# What's the correct way of cutting holes in Blender?

Tags: modeling

I have a question which I keep researching for a past week or two.

What's the correct or "best" so to speak way to cut holes non-destructively and without messing up the topology and without a need to then clean a mesh?

Comment: I think "best" will depend on what is your final application. Are you modeling for rendering, 3D printing, game assets...?

Comment: @Luciano sorry I forgot to mention that in my post. After modelling in blender I'll then need to render it as a product visualisation. Products I produce usually consist from a lot of parts which are connected together so every part should look + function good and clean without any issues.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "non destructively", but shrink-wrap is a great option for cutting holes in complex meshes. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123440/can-blender-be-used-for-high-quality-industrial-design/123471#123471 for details

Answer (score 2):

There is not a single best way and there is really no method that will always give you good topology without a need for some further work.

Since you asked for non-destructive, you've pretty much limited yourself to using boolean operations to cut the holes.  There are add-ons, such as HardOps, that will help you with this process, but none of them will always produce perfect topology every time. Or you can do the same thing manually.

Create your object:

[image: an object to cut]

Create a second object to use to cut the hole

[image: cutter object]

Position the cutter where you want the hole

[image: cutter positioned]

Apply a boolean to the first object, using the 2nd object as the cutter, and set it to difference:

[image: boolean modifier]

Nothing will appear to happen because the cutter is still visible.  A common technique to resolve this is to change the viewport visibility of the cutter by setting 'display as' to wire:

[image: changing the viewport visibility]

When you do this, you can still see the cutter's outline, but also the cut it has made:

[image: cutter in outline]

But you also have to disable rendering the cutter:

[image: don't render the cutter]

As you can see from the matcap display, this works reasonably well:

[image: matcap display]

There are a few other things that can help visibility.  Setting the the cutter to 'shade smooth', and enable auto-smooth for the object often helps, for example.